# Tensorflow splitting training data to batches

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a dataset of images as a Numpy array. (Number of images, length, width, colour range) I would like to split it to batches and feed to tensorflow. What is the good way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you could use [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to divide your images into batches (sub-ndarrays). Then you could feed them to the `tf.Session` using the [`run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) function with the `feed_dict` parameter.

I'd also highly recommend looking at the TF [MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics)

Answer (score 2):

There's a small error in  Thomas Pinetz answer and I can't make comments yet, so here's an extra answer.

`int(len(array)/batch_size)` will round the division down to the nearest integer, so the last batch wouldn't be processed. To round up the division you can use

```
ceil_int = -(-a//b)
```

In addition you might end up with the last batch being very tiny compared to the rest. You can modify your batch size slightly to make this less likely to happen. The complete code is shown below:

```
def ceil(a,b):
    return -(-a//b)

n_samples = len(array)
better_batch_size = ceil(n_samples, ceil(n_samples, batch_size))

for i in range(ceil(n_samples, better_batch_size)):
    batch = array[i * better_batch_size: (i+1) * better_batch_size]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
for bid in range(int(len(array)/batch_size)):
    batch = array[bid*batch_size:(bid+1)*batch_size]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have created your dataset you can just use `batch()` to create batches of the data.

```
>>>dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(8)
>>>dataset = dataset.batch(3)
>>>list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())

[array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7])]
```

You can see more details in [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) about `batch()`